# OpenCV VideoCapture not reading all frames

Tags: java, opencv, video, frames

I'm working on a video processing algorithm in the Java version of OpenCV. I'm using the following functions to read the video file:

```
    VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(video_path);

    if (!camera.isOpened())
        System.out.println("Cannot open file");

    else
    {

        while (true) {
            boolean frameSuccess = camera.read(currentFrame);
            framecount ++;
            System.out.printf("frame: %d", framecount);
            if (frameSuccess != true)
            {   
                break;
            }
```

and then I process the frames one by one.

The problem is that apparently, the program "skips" frames. The variable framecount doesn't correspond to the real number of frames of the video. The videos are in webm format.

Why might be this failing?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score -1):

Ok sometimes due to some lag in processing, missing of frames may occur. But its so rare . Basically when you are reading a video from a file system rather than from a camera using VideoCapture, it read the frames quickly(but it wont skip the frame as far as I know). So to overcome this try to add a delay between each and every frame. We use waitKey in cpp and python. But im not aware for java, possible we would use sleep() I think.